# Pass props to React Router's Link Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing location props to React Router's Link. It successfully navigates me away, but when I click "back" to go back to the previous page, I get an error:

> TypeError Cannot Read property "statusUser" Undefined

It looks like the props are getting messed up when I navigate back.

**Sidebar.js**

```js
Class Sidebar extends Commponent{
render(){    
    return(
     <Link to={
                {
                  pathname: `/user`,
                  state:{
                    statusUser: 'abc',
                  }
                 }
               }><Button>User Menu</Button>
 }
          )
}
```

**User.jsx**

```js
class user extends Component {
  render(){    
    return(
        <UserTable status={this.props.location.state.statusUser}/>
    )
  }
}
```

**UserTable.jsx**

```js
 class UserTable extends Component{
         render(){    
            return(
                     <Link to={
                {
                  pathname: `/user/detail/${this.props.status}`,
                  state:{
                    statusUser: this.props.status,
                  }
                 }
               }><Button>Detail</Button>
            )
          }
    }
```

**UserDetail.jsx**

```js
   class UserDetail extends Component{
             render(){    
                return(
                      <p>{this.props.location.state.statusUser}</p>
                         <Link to={
                    {
                      pathname: `/user`,
                     }
                   }><Button>Back</Button>
                )
              }
        }
```

I think the problem is in User.js. **How do I make the props fixed like using setState or stuff like that inside User.js file?**

Just to be able read the props property, and after reading it go back to the previous page by clicking "back" button.

I'm sorry I just really really new to React so any help would be really appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting that error when you click the Back button in `UserDetail.jsx`. You aren't passing a `state` object to `User.jsx`.

The `User.jsx` component tries to access `this.props.location.state.statusUser`, but `state` doesn't exist, and so it says it can't read the property `statusUser` on `undefined` (`state` is `undefined`).

Here's what you're missing, with a few typos fixed:

```js
// UserDetail.jsx
class UserDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.location.state.statusUser}</p>
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/user`
            // (You aren't passing `state`)
          }}
        >
          <Button>Back</Button>
        </Link>  // <-- You weren't closing Link
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// User.jsx
class User extends Component {  // <-- Capital 'U'
  render() {
    return (
      <UserTable
        status={this.props.location.state.statusUser}  // <-- You require `state`
      />
    );
  }
}
```

As for how to fix it, the easiest way would be to pass a `state` object with your "Back" button in `UserDetail.jsx`.

You can also set `defaultProps` in React. I'm not sure if that's applicable to you, but it lets you provide a fallback for such things:

***Edit:** Include example of defaultProps and propTypes.*

```js
// User.jsx
class User extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserTable
        status={this.props.location.state.statusUser}
      />
    );
  }
}

// Maybe something you put in a different file
const defaultLocation = {
  state: {
    statusUser: '',  // <-- Your default statusUser
  },
};

User.defaultProps = {
  location: defaultLocation,
};

// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
User.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    state: PropTypes.shape({
      statusUser: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })
  })
};
```

I added [**PropTypes**](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) in the above example. It's a way to set checks for the data you're requiring in your components.

Typically, we don't put props into `defaultProps` if it `isRequired`, though, because it will never come to that. If you're unsure what default value to give `statusUser`, I'd recommend starting with making it required in `propTypes`, and then you can refactor in the future if the need arises.

---

There were some bugs with your other code samples, too. I've formatted them below, and fixed the bugs. I'll point out what I fixed in comments:

**Sidebar.js**

```js
class Sidebar extends Component {  // <-- Lowercase 'c'; "Component"
  render() {
    return (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/user`,
          state: {
            statusUser: "abc"
          }
        }}
      >
        <Button>User Menu</Button>
      </Link>  // <-- You weren't closing Link
    );
  }
}
```

**UserTable.jsx**

```js
class UserTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/user/detail/${this.props.status}`,
          state: {
            statusUser: this.props.status
          }
        }}
      >
        <Button>Detail</Button>
      </Link>  // <-- You weren't closing Link
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but I still got a couple questions ,how to set DefaulProps in my code and what should I set into it?

Comment: @Satriastuart I added an example of `defaultProps` and `propTypes` above

Comment: So if I add defaultProps and propTypes in my code ,I don't need to passing back 'state" inside button back.is that true?

Comment: All of these things accomplish different things, so you're going to have to answer that question for yourself. Currently, in `User.jsx`, you're passing `this.props.location.state.statusUser` to the `UserDetails` component. (But `state` doesn't exist, so you're getting your error.) Do you want to always pass a default status, when the `state` isn't there? Use `defaultProps`. Do you want to make sure you always remember to pass `state`? Use `PropTypes.string.isRequired`.